# How to write Unit Test for spark app reading from json file

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark, mocking

I have a simple Spark app in scala. For now, I want my spark app to just create a sparkSession and read Json file into DataFrame.

```scala
object SparkAppExample {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("Spark Scala  Example")
      .getOrCreate()
val records: DataFrame = sparkSession.read.json("records.jsonl")
}
}
```

How to write unit-tests for this? I am able to create a dataframe to test using

```
val dummy: DataFrame = sparkSession.createDataFrame(Seq(
      ("BABY", "videos", "0.5"),
      ("APPLIANCES AND STORAGE", "audios", "0.6")
    ))
```

Now I actually want to call `SparkAppExample.main(Array.empty[String])` within my unit test and then mock `sparkSession.read.json` call to return a dummy data frame I create above.

Answer (score 0):

You could abstract away the things that differ between your app and your test, such as the `SparkSession` and datapath. Like:

```
trait SparkApp {
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
}

object SparkExampleJob extends SparkApp {
    def getRecords(path: String, sparkSession: SparkSession) = sparkSession.read.json(path)
}
```

and in your tests:

```
trait TestUtils extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll with Matchers  {
    val sparkTestSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
}

class SparkAppTest extends TestUtils {

    test("read JSON") {
        val path = "/my/test.json"
        val expectedOutput = List(...)
        SparkExampleJob.getRecords(path, sparkTestSession).collect.toList should equal expectedOutput 
    }
}
```